# How to set a variable using .Evaluate()

Tags: excel, vba

I want to find the nth populated row in a column in excel and I have a formula that works when I just test it out in the actual spreadsheet.  But I'd like to set that value to a variable in a macro using `.Evaluate()`.

After I say `Dim firstRow As Long`, `firstRow = 0`

After I say:

`firstRow = ActiveWorksheet.Evaluate("SMALL(IF($K:$K<>"", ROW($K:$K) - ROW($K$1) + 1), 2)")`

`firstRow` still set to 0.

How do I get the variable to equal the value of the formula evaluation?

I've tried adding `.Select` after the evaluate, I've tried changing firstRow to a `Variant` and those didn't work.

Comment: Are you sure the Activesheet is the correct sheet?  Try replacing it with the actual sheet reference: `firstRow = WorkSheets("Sheet1").Evaluate(...` Changing `Sheet1` to the correct sheet name.

Comment: @ScottCraner Hey Scott sorry that didn't change anything.

Comment: I assume you have a `On Error Resume Next` in your code.  That line errors for me.

Comment: Ah yes I do have that...

Comment: Based on the formula provided in your `Evaluate` method, it looks like you want the row number of the second row that has a populated cell in column K, is that correct?

Comment: @tigeravatar yes that is correct.  The error I get when I remove ```On Error Resume Next``` is ```Object Required```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First it is `ActiveSheet` and second you need to double the `"`

```
firstRow = Activesheet.Evaluate("SMALL(IF($K:$K<>"""", ROW($K:$K) - ROW($K$1) + 1), 2)")
```

Notes:

1. The  `- ROW($K$1) + 1` is not needed with full column references.
2. Do not use `On Error Resume Next` unless absolutely needed.  And then turn the error capture back on with `On Error Goto 0` as soon as possible to catch the errors so they can be dealt with.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, using the Evaluate method with whole column references is quite taxing.  I know it's often tempting to use one-liners for code, but that usually just worsens performance.  To accomplish this same task, I recommend the Range.Find method instead, and it will be less prone to errors:

```
Sub RangeFindMethod()

    Dim rFind As Range
    Dim firstRow As Long

    With ActiveSheet.Columns("K")
        Set rFind = .Find("*", .Cells(.Cells.Count), xlValues, xlWhole, , xlNext)
        If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
            Set rFind = .FindNext(rFind)
            firstRow = rFind.Row
        Else
            firstRow = 1
        End If
    End With

    MsgBox firstRow

End Sub
```

Comment: This. `Evaluate` is VBA telling Excel "you deal with it" - and that's rarely a good idea in code. Use the object model whenever possible (it's likely ~99.99999% always possible).